# Convert DateTime to Date between ASP.NET Server Tags

Tags: asp.net, datetime, webforms

```
<%= CvDetail.DateofBirth %>
```

outputs `03.06.1987 00:00:00`

Tried `<%= CvDetail.DateofBirth.ToString("dd/M/yyyy") %>`

Compile time error, saying `No overload for method 'ToString' takes one argument`.

Comment: Are you positive that `CvDetail.DateofBirth` is a DateTime?

Comment: Yes, but nullable one. 'DateTime?'

Comment: If your positive that it's going to always have a value, you can use `<%= CvDetail.DateofBirth.Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy") %>` Otherwise, use a ternary operator to show a default if the date is null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [handling null datetime in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23685016/handling-null-datetime-in-gridview)

Comment: It worked. Still wondering why ToString() cannot take one argument

Comment: Because it's a nullable DateTime, which doesn't have the overridden `ToString()` function. To access the underlying DateTime object, you have to access it via the `.Value` But beware that can cause a null reference exception, which is why I suggested the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, converting to DateTime before ToString solved it for me.
c# code:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(CvDetail.DateofBirth.Value).ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

or

```
String.Format("{0:dd/M/yyyy}", CvDetail.DateofBirth.Value);
```

Lemme know if it helps.

Comment: This doesn't apply to nullable date time types `DateTime?`

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the nullable, fixed it now